# Applying Mapnik style for OpenStreetMap data in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, openstreetmap, symbology, mapnik

I am loading OpenStreetMap vector data into ArcMap (using the Download and Symbolize OSM Data tool of [ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap 1.1](http://esriosmeditor.codeplex.com)). I'm sure there must be a simple way to apply the style/symbols of the Mapnik baselayer as rendered on the OSM website ([example](http://osm.org/go/uN@RwVOe--)), rather than using the ArcMap defaults or manually adjusting symbology for each feature type, but I just can't figure it out.

Can someone point me to a potential solution?

Comment: The link in rrush answer is dead, but I recently discovered it was cached in the Internet Archive and can be downloaded via:
http://web.archive.org/web/20111212160630/http://www.esriuk.com/developerhub/dh_downloads/OSM.zip Good Luck, Omer

Comment: Closing as the links are dead now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently found myself in the same situation. After scouring about the web I came across an MXD that is ready to go. You used to be able to find download links at this page http://opengeodata.org/?sort=&search=esri%20uk.  The direct link to the MXD at the Esri UK site used to be here http://www.esriuk.com/developerhub/dh_downloads/OSM.zip.  It is not the exact same Mapnik rendering but it is very close.  Being inland in the US, I removed the Mainland layer and changed the map frame background to a light gray instead of the blue so I could see water features.

---

See [Mapnik style for OSM Data in ArcGIS](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/16251/mapnik-style-for-osm-data-in-arcgis) for an alternative link to an MXD that may be suitable.

Comment: Thanks Ray. I haven't fired up Windows for a while, but will give this a shot next time I'm working with ArcMap. I appreciate the answer, it sounds promising!

Comment: Unfortunately the links are dead. Do you guys still have a copy of the mxd?

Comment: See O_M's comment [above](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9838/how-to-apply-mapnik-style-for-osm-data-in-arcmap#comment99765_9838).

Comment: update is here osm forum https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/16251/mapnik-style-for-osm-data-in-arcgis