# Availability of MXD file for OpenStreetMap data in Esri Geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap

From what I understand, an ArcGIS mxd file contains the "styling" information on how to show data.

I downloaded and imported OpenStreetMap data into my geodatabase. Now I need to show them.

Is there any available mxd file match the OpenStreetMap fields/values that I can use?

I check this question([How to apply Mapnik style for OSM data in ArcMAP?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9838/how-to-apply-mapnik-style-for-osm-data-in-arcmap)), but the links are all dead.

ps: right now the all the highway/roads/trail display as a single line in my map. I want to use mxd to show them in a better way, like Mapnik or google.

Comment: I believe what you're after is a layer file (.lyr) which contains the source and styling information for the data. If you can get the layer file you can reset the link(s).

Comment: thx. now the problem is where to find the lyr file?

Comment: you could try this one http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3daa73d933b7415997c37145a6094fe0

Comment: OSM.zip http://web.archive.org/web/20111212160630/http://www.esriuk.com/developerhub/dh_downloads/OSM.zip has the file for Mapnik .lyr  and .mxd files from ESRI (UK)

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson thx. I tried that. It provides the basemap but my app is intranet, so nah.

Comment: Looks like @Mapperz has the right one for the intranet. Get in quick though, Esri is rearranging their web sites so the link may go dead fairly quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OpenStreetMap plugin, you should see a "Symbolize OSM Data" tool (also present are "Symbolize Lines," "Symbolize Points," and "Symbolize Polygons."

If you feed your line/point/poly feature classes into this tool it will add your data to the MXD (in a "Group" layer) in a pre-styled way where different features have different styles based on their osm attributes.  The authors of the plugin made this symbology.

The style doesn't match the official OSM or Google basemaps as you would see online, but it is a starting point and will look better than single lines... and you can tweak anything however you like.